# mysql: join with no record match on table

Tags: mysql

if i have 2 or many tables with no record on 1 table or some tables,

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(`id1` int, `date1` datetime, `val1` int)
;
INSERT INTO t1
(`id1`, `date1`,`val1`)
VALUES  
(1, '2013-11-10 14:57:09',10),
(2, '2013-11-10 16:59:37',15),
(4, '2013-11-11 15:12:44',11)
;

CREATE TABLE t2
(`id2` int, `date2` datetime, `val2` int)
;
INSERT INTO t2
(`id2`, `date2`,`val2`)
VALUES  
(1, '2013-11-10 14:57:09',22),
(2, '2013-11-10 16:59:37',4),
(4, '2013-11-12 12:12:44',7)
;
```

i use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1,t2
WHERE 
  (t1.date1 >= '2013-11-11 13:00:00'  AND t1.date1 < '2013-11-11 15:00:00')  and 
  (t2.date2 >= '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND t2.date2 < '2013-11-11 23:59:59') 
LIMIT 1
```

and the output

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Because no record match on table t2

If i want the output like this

```
+------+---------------------+------+------+
| id1  | date1               | val1 | val2 |
+------+---------------------+------+------+
|    1 | 2013-11-10 14:57:09 |   10 |    0 |
+------+---------------------+------+------+
```

is this possible?

Comment: Actually, it's not quite clear what exactly you want to get. If you need to get only lines of `t1` that don't have corresponding records in `t2`, that's rather trivial to accomplish - with [NOT IN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6223/1), or with LEFT JOIN, doesn't matter.

Comment: i want all field on t1 and t2. i have tried with left join, cross join, outer join, if null. The problem is, the output returned empty result, because no record match based on with where clause condition

Comment: on [NOT IN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6223/1), where's val2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. Any conditions on the table being joined must be in the `ON` clause, because putting them in the `WHERE` clause will filter out the null matches.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.date2 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
WHERE t1.date1 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
```

Here's how to do it with 4 tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.date2 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.date3 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t3.date4 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
WHERE t1.date1 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
```

Comment: if i have 4 or more table, how the syntax?

Comment: Just add more `LEFT JOIN` clauses for each table.

Comment: like this script:? SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (t2,t3,t4) ON (t2.date2,t3.date3,t4.date4) BETWEEN '2013-11-11 00:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 23:59:59'
WHERE t1.date1 BETWEEN '2013-11-11 13:00:00'  AND '2013-11-11 15:00:00'

Comment: I said to add more `LEFT JOIN` clauses, not to add more tables to the same `LEFT JOIN` clause. See the updated answer.